# How can you replay old data into dataflow via pub/sub and maintain correct event time logic?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We're trying to use dataflow's processing-time independence to start up a new streaming job and replay all of our data into it via Pub/Sub but are running into the following problem:

The first stage of the pipeline is a groupby on a transaction id, with a session window of 10s discarding fired panes and no allowed lateness. So if we don't specify the timestampLabel of our replay pub/sub topic then when we replay into pub/sub all of the event timestamps are the same and the groupby tries to group all of our archived data into transaction id's for all time. No good.

If we set the timestampLabel to be the actual event timestamp from the archived data, and replay say 1d at a time into the pub/sub topic then it works for the first day's worth of events, but then as soon as those are exhausted the data watermark for the replay pub/sub somehow jumps forward to the current time, and all subsequent replayed days are dropped as late data. I don't really understand why that happens, as it seems to violate the idea that dataflow logic is independent of the processing time.

If we set the timestampLabel to be the actual event timestamp from the archived data, and replay all of it into the pub/sub topic, and then start the streaming job to consume it, the data watermark never seems to advance, and nothing ever seems to come out of the groupby. I don't really understand what's going on with that either.

Comment: Could you clarify what you use to write the historical data to pubsub, how much data is there, and are you writing it in order of event time or in arbitrary order? Also, it would help to see a job ID of the jobs that are too slow, for your approaches #2 or #3.

Comment: Originally we had a single batch job that read the data from a bq table and wrote it to pub/sub. After that didn't work (we assumed because it was too much data on the same timestamp) we changed it to running a series of batch jobs replaying a single day at a time, because that was the only we could find to read from bq in any kind of order. So it's in arbitrary order within a day, but the days are ordered. The current run I'm looking at has around 1M events archived, but once in production it will be billions. A job id for approach #2 is 2016-11-02_11_05_48-11273762957648435844 still running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approaches #2 and #3 are suffering from different issues:

Approach #3 (write all data, then start consuming): Since data is written to the pubsub topic out-of-order, the watermark really cannot advance until all (or most) of the data is consumed - because the watermark is a soft guarantee "further items that you receive you are unlikely to have event time later than this", but due to out-of-order publishing there is no correspondence whatsoever between publish time and event time. So your pipeline is effectively stuck until it finishes processing all this data.

Approach #2: technically it suffers from the same problem within each particular day, but I suppose the amount of data within 1 day is not that large, so the pipeline is able to process it. However, after that, the pubsub channel stays empty for a long time, and in that case the current implementation of `PubsubIO` will advance the watermark to real time, that's why further days of data are declared late. [The documentation](https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/PubsubUnboundedSource.java#L85-L90) explains this some more.

In general, quickly catching up with a large backlog, e.g. by using historic data to "seed" the pipeline and then continuing to stream in new data, is an important use case that we currently don't support well.

Meanwhile I have a couple of recommendations for you:

- (better) Use a variation on approach #2, but try timing it against the streaming pipeline so that the pubsub channel doesn't stay empty.
- Use approach #3, but with more workers and more disk per worker (your current job appears to be using autoscaling with max 8 workers - try something much larger, like 100? It will downscale after it catches up)

Comment: Great information, thanks. I don't know why I didn't check the javadocs, but can I suggest a link be added to that section or that information be added here? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io#using-user-specified-timestamps
I forgot to mention approach #3 was still doing the replay 1 day at a time, so it should have been roughly ordered. I'm guessing that's not enough. I think I have enough to figure something that will work at least now though

Comment: Aside: It's incredibly difficult to do the "timing" thing when the time for a job to decide to reset to the watermark to now is less than the amount of time it takes to spin up a new job writing the next chunk of data =/

Comment: Hmm, depending on the amount of data, you may be able to run the "publisher" job on your local machine using DirectRunner. Though I guess that doesn't get rid of BigQuery export latency.

Comment: Definitely not, it'll be hundreds of gigs in prod. Also, just some clarification, if I'm buffering up all the rows in pub/sub with sequentially-run days in approach #3, why does that not work? Do the rows not come out in roughly the order they were written? I guess the job seeing a huge backlog of pub/sub data spins up a bunch more readers?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I don't understand the difference between #2 and #3, can you clarify it once more?

Comment: #2 we start the job that consumes the p/s topic, then start sequentially replaying day by day the data into the topic. #3 we replay day by day the data into the topic, then start the job that consumes it when that's done. I'd think this would end up with the same behaviour, but in #3 it locks up at the groupby

Comment: I see, this makes sense. The most likely explanation is that PubSub provides no ordering guarantees whatsoever when consuming the backlog (the order is effectively random) - so in #3 you are dealing with a huge pile of unordered data, while in #2 you are able to consume at least some of it (1 day) while it arrives.

Comment: Yeah that makes perfect sense, it's just like I said frustrating, as it makes timing the sequential run of jobs with the consumption very difficult without accidentally having the watermark reset to now. I'm guessing I'll have to set up something that polls the p/s subscription's backlog size and kicks off the next job when it goes under a threshold =/

Comment: Make sure to first try the simpler solution, which is using autoscaling with a lot more workers.